# Interface inheritance with IDisposable?

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have the following inheritance hierarchy:

```
public interface IRepository<T> : IDisposable
{
    void Add(T model);
    void Update(T model);

    int GetCount();

    T GetById(int id);
    ICollection<T> GetAll();
}

public interface IAddressRepository : IRepository<Address>
{
}
```

And this code:

```
var adrs = new Address[]{
    new Address{Name="Office"}
};

using (IAddressRepository adrr = new AddressRepository())
    foreach (var a in adrs)
        adrr.Add(a);
```

However, this code does not compile. It gives me this error message:

```
Error   43  
'Interfaces.IAddressRepository': type used in a using statement must be
 implicitly convertible to 'System.IDisposable'
```

However, a parent of `IAddressRepository` inherits from `IDisposable`.

What is happening here? How do I make the code compile?

Comment: Can we see your `AddressRepository` class - this should work if it's implementing properly (though a different error should occur if it isn't!).

Comment: Can you show the definition of AddressRepository?  Right now, you only are showing IAddressRepository.

Comment: can you add ur implementation of AddressRepository?

Comment: Whoops! You're right, I missed a (public) accessability modifier on the superclass of `AddressRepository`. The errors produced by cross-assembly problems like this are not very descriptive! I don't know if I should delete this question, or accept ChrisShain's answer, which led me to find the problem.

Comment: Either way- it's probably worth keeping in case someone else makes the same mistake.

Comment: @Oliver You can't delete it now that it has an answer; I would argue that the answer question and answer are valuable, too. Chris' answer could even be updated to be more explicit in answering what exactly it was, now that we know.

Comment: Just so I know what to add to the answer- was the problem that the assembly containing `AddressRepository`'s parent class was not compiling?

Comment: @ChrisShain That's right. `AddressRepository` was known about, but it's parent class was not `public`, which either stopped the assembly compiling, or otherwise broke it in some weird way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My guess is that you are making a mistake- either you have not recompiled the assembly containing the `IRepository<T>` interface since you made it inherit from `IDisposable`, or you are referencing the wrong copy of it, or you are referencing some other `IAddressRepository`.

Try doing a Clean, then a Rebuild All, and check the paths on your references.  If the projects are in the same solution, make sure you are referencing the project containing `IRepository<T>` / `IAddressRepository` and not the DLL.

Also make sure that `AddressRepository` *actually implements* `IAddressRepository`.  It might just be reporting the wrong error.

EDIT: So the resolution seems to be that the assembly containing `AddressRepository`'s parent class was not compiling.  This caused the debugger to complain about `AddressRepository` not implementing `IDisposable`, rather than the (more sensible) " inaccessible due to its protection level" error compiling the class itself.  My guess is you had that error too, but were addressing this one first.

Answer (score 2):

Works for me:

```
using System;

public class Address {}

public interface IRepository<T> : IDisposable
{
    void Add(T model);
    void Update(T model);
}

public interface IAddressRepository : IRepository<Address>
{
}

class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        using (var repo = GetRepository())
        {
        }
    }

    private static IAddressRepository GetRepository()
    {
        // TODO: Implement :)
        return null;
    }
}
```

I suspect you may have two `IAddressRepository` interfaces. Are you sure it's `Interfaces.IAddressRepository` that extends `IRepository<T>`, and that that extends `IDisposable`?